# What is PPPOE line protocol?

Tags: isp, pppoe, ppp

In serial wan connection we use PPP or HDLC line protocols,but where would we use PPPOE?

What is Ethernet in this term 'PPPOE'?

Comment: PPP was used for dialup connections.  As we moved into the Internet era there were still systems (ISPs) that required that protocol until they upgraded, so PPoE was a kludge to make it possible.  You probably will not see it anywhere anymore.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

PPPoE (Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet) is a specification for connecting multiple computer users on an Ethernet local area network to a remote site through common customer premises equipment, which is the telephone company's term for a modem and similar devices. PPPoE can be used to have an office or building-full of users share a common Digital Subscriber Line (DSL), cable modem, or wireless connection to the Internet. PPPoE combines the Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP), commonly used in dialup connections, with the Ethernet protocol, which supports multiple users in a local area network. The PPP protocol information is encapsulated within an Ethernet frame.

Source:
http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/PPPoE

Answer (score 1):

PPPoE stands for Point-to-point protocol over Ethernet. It is protocol designed to transmit PPP frames over Ethernet network with additional Ethernet header. This protocol is used for obtaining PPP software properties (e. g. call to some station and thereby establish stateful connection) over Ethernet infrastructure.